# what's the difference between terminate() and stop() in groovy

Tags: groovy

in the following URL

http://www.gpars.org/guide/

It sometime use terminate() and sometime use stop(). Are they the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the documentation for [`stop`](http://gpars.org/0.12/javadoc/groovyx/gpars/actor/impl/SequentialProcessingActor.html#stop%28%29)

> Send message to stop to the actor. All messages in queue will be processed before stopped but no new messages will be accepted after that point

and [`terminate`](http://gpars.org/0.12/javadoc/groovyx/gpars/actor/impl/SequentialProcessingActor.html#terminate%28%29)

> Terminate the Actor. The background thread will be interrupted, unprocessed messages will be passed to the afterStop method, if exists. Has no effect if the Actor is not started.

See the difference?  It's all about how it handles shutdown and what it does with unprocessed messages.